# Why builder lost type?

Tags: java, generics

When I try something like this

```
public class Example<T> {
    private T value;

    private Example() {

    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <T> Builder<T> builder() {
        return new Builder<>();
    }

    public static class Builder<T> {
        public Example<T> build() {
            return new Example<>();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example<String> example = Example.builder().build();
        example.setValue("test");
        System.out.println(example.getValue().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

I get an error

```
Example.java:27: error: incompatible types: Example<Object> cannot be converted to Example<String>
        Example<String> example = Example.builder().build();
```

But when I add type to arguments of `builder` method, everything works fine

```
public static <T> Builder<T> builder(T type) {
    return new Builder<>();
}
```

Why? And how I can rid off this dummy type argument?

Bonus question: How to pass complex type to the method like this?

```
public static <T> Builder<T> builder(Class<T> type) {
    return new Builder<>();
}

Example<Optional<String>> example = Example.builder(???).build();
```

**UPDATE:** It's only an example. The real-life application will have several builders creating each other on different stages of the building process and of course, they will have methods accepting generic type. I hope there is a way to help the compiler infer types. I even agree to tricks with reflection, if any exist and they can help me to get a beautiful DSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Example` is a raw class, so implicitly `T` is `Object`. You can specify the generic type when calling the method by putting it in angle-brackets (`<>`) before the method call:

```java
Example<String> example = Example.<String>builder().build();
// Here --------------------------^
```

Comment: Yes, it's works. But it's so ugly :( Can it be done in another way?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can infer that the `Example` you are trying to create is an `Example<String>`, but it can't infer that the `Builder` returned by `builder()` method should be a `Builder<String>`.

You can help the compiler by breaking the statement into two statements:

```
Builder<String> builder = Example.builder();
Example<String> example = builder.build();
```

Or by specifying the type of `Builder` you expect from the `builder()` method:

```
Example<String> example = Example.<String>builder().build();
```

Comment: No fluent interface for me :(

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind an **Unchecked assignment warning** you **could** add just the following change:

```
    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder<>();
    }
```

EDIT Start:

Additionally, if you want to omit the warning you can change the `Builder` class into:

```
    public static class Builder {
        private <T> Example<T> build() {
           return new Example<>();
        }
    }
```

and change the static `Builder` method to:

```
public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
}
```

EDIT End.

and then you can use it like this:

```
Example<String> example = Example.builder().build();
```

Comment: I would like to do without it.

Comment: i get that, but from the other comments i concluded you were looking for a syntactically prettier solution :-)